# Linq marking duplicates in a list base on multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq

A list of `Product`s is imported from another process the agreed rules state  that each batch cannot have duplicates in the combined fields 
1-`Name`, 2-`Category` and 3-`Section`.
If duplicates found then each list items `Status` fields is set to `-1` where  duplicate we found.

The below code is my attempt using Linq it does return the correct results, however it does not feel smooth and could be difficult to maintain.  I would like to make it more generic, readable and extensible would this be the appropriate place to add an extension method passing in the columns to verify for duplicates? If so what would this look like?

```
public class Product
{
    public int BatchId {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public char Section { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Location {get;set;}
}

public enum ImportStatus
{
    Duplicate = -1,
    AwaitingProcess = 0
}

void Main()
{
    List<Product> productList = new List<Product>()
    { 
        new Product(){BatchId =1,Name="Ginger",Category="Fresh", Section=   'B',Status=  0,   Location="Produce"}
        ,new Product(){BatchId=1,Name="turmeric",Category="Fresh",   Section=   'B',Status=  0, Location="Front Counter"}
        ,new Product(){BatchId=1,Name="LEMON",Category="Fruit",   Section=  'B',Status=  0, Location="Name Area"}
        ,new Product(){BatchId=1,Name="LEMON",Category="Fruit",   Section=  'B',Status=  0, Location="Outer Court"}
        ,new Product(){BatchId=1,Name="lettuce",Category="Produce", Section='X',Status=  0, Location="Produce"}
        ,new Product(){BatchId=1,Name="Lettuce",Category="Product", Section='X',Status=  0, Location="Freezer"}
        ,new Product(){BatchId=1,Name="Apple",Category="Fruit",   Section=  'S',Status=  0, Location="Product"}
        ,new Product(){BatchId=1,Name="Apple",Category="Fruit", Section=    'S',Status=  0, Location="Front Counter"}
    };


    List<Product> filteredProductList  =productList
    .Where (l => l.Status==0)
    .GroupBy (r=>new {  r.Name,r.Category,r.Section},( grp, tbl)=> new{GROUP=grp,TBL=tbl})
    .Where (r => r.TBL.Count()>1)
    .SelectMany(r=>r.TBL)
    .Select(r=>new Product {BatchId=r.BatchId, Name=r.Name,Category=r.Category,Section= r.Section,Location=r.Location,Status=(int)ImportStatus.Duplicate})
    .Union(productList   
    .Where (l => l.Status==0)
    .GroupBy (r=>new  {  r.Name,r.Category,r.Section},( grp, tbl)=> new{GROUP=grp,TBL=tbl})
    .Where (r => r.TBL.Count()==1)
    .SelectMany(r=>r.TBL)
    .Select (r =>new Product{BatchId=r.BatchId, Name=r.Name,Category=r.Category,Section= r.Section,Location=r.Location,Status=0}) 
    )
    .ToList();

    // Result of FilterProductionList =
    // 1 LEMON Fruit B -1 Name Area 
    // 1 LEMON Fruit B -1 Outer Court 
    // 1 Apple Fruit S -1 Product 
    // 1 Apple Fruit S -1 Front Counter 
    // 1 Ginger Fresh B 0 Produce 
    // 1 turmeric Fresh B 0 Front Counter 
    // 1 lettuce Produce X 0 Produce 
    // 1 Lettuce Product X 0 Freezer
}
```

Comment: Can't you just clean out your products list so you have no duplicates anymore? To me, it seems your datastructure should be evaluated, which leads to your overly complex linq structure

Comment: Every record that comes through must be accounted for, by updating the status field I have a log of each record that will be stored . Perhaps this is not the best way to solve this problem but to split the original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not follow your logic at first glance. This solution will be better for readability and maintainability.

```
foreach (Product product in productList) 
{
    int dupCount = productList.Count(p => p.Name == product.Name 
                                     && p.Category == product.Category 
                                     && p.Section == product.Section);
    if (dupCount > 1) 
        product.Status = (int)ImportStatus.Duplicate;
}
```

Edit:
It's not always better to use LINQ expressions, especially when you're calling multiple .Where(), .Select(), and .GroupBy(). Don't always rule out loops when we can leverage them here. In this solution you can avoid wasting any extra space introducing another data structure to hold your new filtered product list. Also, instead of instantiating new `Product` objects, we can keep the original and just update their `Status` properties.

Comment: It's not efficient to do the query in each iteration of `productList`.

Comment: It's not efficient but he asked about "I would like to make it more generic, readable and extensible"

Comment: If a bad solution is readable, that doesn't make it an acceptable solution. Just suppose only 2% of a million values is duplicated. You better filter them before iterating.

Comment: Right you would want to filter before iterating for efficiency/scalability, but It's a trade off.

Answer (score 1):

No need to re-create all products. The most efficient way is to loop through the products having duplicates and set their `Status` property:

```
foreach (var product in productList
    .Where (p => p.Status == 0)
    .GroupBy (p => new { p.Name, p.Category, p.Section },
        (grp, tbl) => new { GROUP= grp, TBL= tbl } )
    .Where (g => g.TBL.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g.TBL).ToList())
{
    product.Status = -1;
}
```